# Google Analyics shows very inaccurate on Active Users

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics

My Google Analytics shows very inaccurate on Active Users. I even tried adding a heartbeat event to it,

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    ga("send", "event", "HeartBeat", "30s");
}, 30000);
```

but I'm still failing on getting the Active users accurate, I'm expecting at least 30-45 Active Users but I keep getting around 2-10. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure, that u're not really  just getting so less users? Maybe Google isn't checking in the right place.

Comment: @RaisingAgent I'm very sure that's wrong info `app.run(["$rootScope", "$location", function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () {
        ga("send", "pageview", $location.path());
    });

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        ga("send", "event", "HeartBeat", "30s");
    }, 50000);
}]);` where I assigned all my modules to app.

Comment: As for your test events, are you looking in "realtime events" or in "realtime users"? Because even though you're firing a ton of events to test...you're still only considered one user. If you look under Real Time > Events -- you should see all of your test events firing every 30000ms.  As for the virtual pageviews, I'm not sure what to think...you should be seeing them. Any JS erros?

Comment: @RaisingAgent I have no javascript errors. I'm looking in "realtime users"